# Searching for text in module using dxl

Tags: ibm-doors

How do you search for text in module using dxl script. Once found I want to highlight the object in which the text was found

Comment: what do you mean by "highlighting"? the same thing as the GUI does when you use the search function, but highlighting all occurrences of the text at once? that is not possible in DOORS, as highlight here means "mark", as in shift-cursor-keys - and you don't have more than one cursor

Comment: I mean marking ame as when you use the find option from the tool bar

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The corresponding DXL Perm for highlighting is

**Declaration**

```
bool highlightText(Object, int start, int stop, int colIndex, bool isHeading)
```

**Operation**

Highlights text in the given module, in the given column from cursor position start to cursor position stop.

**Example**

```
//Highlights the first 10 characters of the current objects heading
highlightText(current Object, 10, 20, 1, true)
```

Note that only one object can be highlighted at one time.
Look at chapter "Object searching" in the DXL manual for other perms you might need in this context.

For searching I would suggest the perm `contains`

**Declaration**

```
int contains(Buffer b, char ch [,int offset])
int contains(Buffer b, string word, int offset)
```

**Operation**

The first form returns the index at which the character ch appears in buffer b, starting from 0. If present, the value of
offset controls where the search starts. For example, if offset is 1, the search starts from 2. If offset is not
present, the search starts from 0. If ch does not appear after offset, the function returns -1.
The second form returns the index at which string word appears in the buffer, starting from 0, provided the string is
preceded by a non-alphanumeric character. The value of the mandatory offset argument controls where the search
starts. If word does not appear after offset, the function returns -1.

Comment: Thanks Mike. I will start with perm contain